# How to set the owner of tar files and its contents to current user

Tags: permissions, directory

I need to set the owner of tar files and its contents to be set as current user.

I will receive files from user FOO in the folder **config_files/billing/xml/incommingBills**   i want to set owner as current user i.e BAR whenever a tar file is copied to this location. Also want the contents of tar file to be set as BAR.

Answer (score 1):

If you're taking about the `tar` file itself, either the owner of the file or the root user must `chown newusername /path/to/file`.  Or you, if you have superuser access, can `sudo chown $(whoami) /path/to/file`.

If you are talking about ownership information contained *within* the `tar` file, I will defer to the manual:

```
 -o      (x mode) Use the user and group of the user running the program rather than those specified in the archive.  Note that this has no significance unless -p is specified, and the program is being run by the root user.  In this case,
         the file modes and flags from the archive will be restored, but ACLs or owner information in the archive will be discarded.
```

Comment: will it set the owner as whoami to files and folders inside the tar file also ? Do i need to run above every time or will it be executed whenever file is copied to this location cause copying of file is automatic.

Comment: See my edit to handle ownership of files _within_ the tar file, which your question did not clarify was about which you were asking.